# Sizing AC fuse for a DC device

Tags: power, current, fuses

I have an enclosure which consists of a power entry module and a 24V DC power supply. So inside the enclosure, the 24V DC power supply is powered by the 230V AC through the power entry module. And this 24V DC power supply will be used to supply/source 3A current to a 8 Ohm load which is a heater.

The power entry module for the AC mains side needs fuses to be installed across both line and the neutral.

As far as I know I need to install slow blow type AC fuses.

But how should I estimate the current rating for the AC power entry module's fuses?

Comment: Do you have any specs for ripple on rated load and surge current? Or other relevant info like fast or slow blow recommended?

Comment: You might want to start with the maximum expected current that should flow in normal operation...

Comment: 3A through the resistor. I estimate in case 4A max current. I ignore transients.

Comment: 8 Ohm with 3A is 72 Watt. 72/230 = 320mA. Does that mean a 1A fuse would be proper?

Comment: What are the fuses trying to protect? Think about this because this determines why you put fuses in and what rating they should be.

Comment: @Andyaka The fuses needed to be installed in the power entry module aka power socket. I guess they are needed if there is over current due to hazard short ect. The power supply is 24VDC 4A rated. The load is 8 Ohm means 3A current. The fuses will be on line and neutral. I thought it is easy to size at least a rule of thumb. It is an easy setup I thought sizing fuses wouldn’t be that complicated.

Comment: You still haven't said what the fuses are protecting.

Comment: @Andyaka I dont know but I guess the power supply.  The power entry module is a filter with fuse sockets.

Comment: I mean this kind of module http://www.westek.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/IEC-Inlet-Filter.jpeg is powering the DC power supply

Comment: Fuses are normally to prevent infrastructure (wiring in walls for example) causing a fire, Fuses are not usually present to prevent failure to a power supply. This is why I ask because you need to understand what you are trying to protect and rate accordingly. Of course if the power supply is a fire hazard under a single fault condition then you have to use a fuse that will prevent it burning too. See what I mean about knowing what the fuses are for.

Comment: So in my case they are not even necessary¿ 1A or 10A fuse does not matter..

Answer (score 2):

[Littelfuse](http://www.littelfuse.com) makes and distributes fuses (and numerous other overcurrent protection devices), and they also offer very good technical assistance. Their [SWITCH MODE POWER SUPPLIES APPLICATION NOTE](http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics_technical/application_notes/fuses/littelfuse_switch_mode_power_supplies_application_note.pdf) is a good place to start, and may just answer your question without further investigation. I have contacted them many times for assistance, and their application engineers have always been very helpful. It can be difficult to get the amount of protection you need while at the same time minimizing false trips, so don't hesitate to ask them for guidance.

Comment: not a real answer, sounds like an advertisement.

Comment: looks like sound advice for a newbie with example white papers.. @SirSy rather it's not a real question with specs or datasheets links

Comment: Not an advertisement - I have no involvement with Littelfuse except as a highly satisfied (former) customer. I've worked with more component manufacturers and suppliers than I can count, and I have always found this company to be extremely helpful. Regardless, the document is very good, especially s a starting point for a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Adding fuses to a PEM should only be required for redundancy breaker rating protection such that shared current on the breaker does not draw more than the nameplate current rating used for breaker load calculations.

As far as protecting the PSU device, **its design ought to include fuses for protecting itself** and possibly also the breaker from drawing more than its defined rating.

Since EU power is 2 line, you have a choice of single or dual fuse protection to remove voltage from either or both.  Your regional standards must be understood to know which applies.

Here is an example of a power entry model with built-in fuse options specified by the OEM with ratings for single an dual fuses.

[image]

A quick Rule of thumb is if the DC rating on the PSU is 100W then at 240V one might be looking at a 100W/240Vac= 0.25A to 1A fuse which is trivial for breaker protection.

Comment: “0.25A to 1A fuse which is trivial for breaker protection.” What do you mean by that¿ Do. you mean CB inside the PSU  will already trip much before the fuse would do? The fuse is completely unnecessary?

Comment: you did not mention CB, and thus a fuse is not necessary. I meant adding say a 0.5A fuse to 0.24A load rating is not significantly reduce your mains 10A breaker capacity. for example.

Comment: There is no CB in PSU I thought u said that. Misunderstood

Comment: Normally these PEM used for enclosures which powers DC power supplies. I wonder why would they add fuse sockets if not necessary.

Comment: OK then a fault condition rating for fuse(s) must factor aging from surge currents and protection built into PSU and use OEM recommended sizing. Eg. 0.5A to 1A I expect